# Python ImportErrors while trying to get a program (found on Google Code) to work

Tags: python, setup, python-2.7

I'm trying to install a program written in Python / -->*http://code.google.com/p/amphetype/*<-- / 

I did subversion checkout

```
svn checkout http://amphetype.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ amphetype-read-only
```

and tried to setup / run the program, but I am seeing **ImportErrors** like that:

```
pm@machina-pm:/home/pn/amphetype-read-only$ python setup.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    import py2exe
ImportError: No module named py2exe
```

and:

```
pm@machina-pm:/home/pn/amphetype-read-only$ python Amphetype.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Amphetype.py", line 10, in <module>
    from Config import Settings
  File "/home/pn/amphetype-read-only/Config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from QtUtil import *
  File "/home/pn/amphetype-read-only/QtUtil.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore
```

**EDIT:**
installing python-qt (`sudo apt-get install python-qt4`) helped in getting rid of the second ImportError.
However program still doesn't start, now it says:

```
pm@machina-pm:/home/pn/amphetype$ python Amphetype.py
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Amphetype.py: cannot connect to X server :0
```

PS. *readme.txt* that goes with the source code sadly doesn't get me very far (author  says that it was developed under windows, and the whole project seems to be abandoned now). I used to use that software on Windows and I like it a lot, and would love to get it running on Linux.

**EDIT 2:**
Ufff...
 It works at last, moving the *amphetype* directory from **`~/amphetype`** to **`/etc/amphetype`** did the trick, although I'm not sure why...

Comment: Works fine for me actually on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

Comment: What computer are you running it on? 'cannot connect to X server' sounds like you're running it on a server or something without a graphical environment.

Comment: Hmmm, strange... I do have X. Unity works fine. It's a regular desktop computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`py2exe` can only run on windows so I don't know how you can get round that.  Maybe using wine.

you can get round the `ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore` by installing `python-qt4`

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

Comment: py2exe is used to make a windows executable. It'll be of no use to a linux user.

Comment: Javier Rivera is right, and besides that, the command is wrong. It should be: `python setup.py install` or `build` instead of `install` depending on what you want. Also note that there's a `readme.txt` which will get you going.

Comment: Thanks @Timo please tell me how you think that making windows executables on Linux is useless. I can think of cases where it will be great for me at least.

Comment: Hmm, my comment is maybe a bit misplaced. It could easily go under the question. Well, apparently py2exe produces invalid binaries when run under Wine. Atleast when I looked it up, maybe it got fixed by now. But still, just to run the program, you don't need to install it, and definatly no need to compile it into a Windows binary. It's a badly written `setup.py` file.